# Where should we ask for code explanations?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am trying to learn deep learning in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29). I am teaching myself about this subject on the Internet and am using other web tutorials.

But as I am new to this area I usually have questions regarding code in those tutorials. I have asked my questions on Stack Exchange, *[Code explanation of Python code in deep learning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39496355)*, but it got instantly downvoted and voted for closing. This response I actually expected, but before asking I went through the meta post *[Where to ask for code explanation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188079/where-to-ask-for-code-explanation)* and only then did I write my question.

As I am a learner (and like most new language coders) I would have some questions regarding code, and I know Stack Overflow is not the right Stack Exchange site for those post then where should I ask code explanation-related questions?

Comment: These kind of questions usually tend to be too broad. It's better to learn code explanations from books, and not at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I taught myself how to program, well before Stack Overflow was a twinkle in Joel and Jeff's eyes. Perhaps shockingly, I was still able to learn to do it. When I had a "doubt", I tried to do it how I thought it should work. If I got an error, I tried something else. I read the documentation, books, and magazines. Later, the World Wide Web came along and made things easier to find, but I still rarely ask questions because trying things almost always results in success. I highly encourage you to learn how to debug so that you can try things out. I also encourage you to learn how to research.

Comment: It helps to ask a single question per question.  It also may help to have a firm grasp on a language before trying to do something complex like training neural networks.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is not that you're looking for an explanation of a topic, rather than code to solve a problem, the problem is simply the scope and clarity of what you're looking for an explanation of.  Not only are the questions that you're asking very broad questions asking for entire high level concepts to be explained in entirety, but you're asking *lots* of different questions, many of which aren't even really related to each other.

If you ask a *single*, **specific** question, in which it's very clear what exactly you do and don't understand about the topic/code/whatever, what you're looking to have explained, and where explaining that topic can reasonably be answered in a few paragraphs (at most) *then* the question would be appropriate.

If you're looking for entire high level concepts to be explained then you'll need to look elsewhere, whether it be books, courses, etc. that are designed to convey information of that scope.

Answer (score 4):

This exists for a reason:

[image]

If it qualifies for this, you are just wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

Since we cannot mark a question as a duplicate of one in another site, I will quote answer marked as correct in [the very question you linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188079/where-to-ask-for-code-explanation):

> On Stack Overflow, assuming the question is of sufficient quality.
>
> FYI "Please explain this: [code dump]" is not of sufficient quality. You should be explaining specifically what you do and don't understand about that code snippet, provide some context (how was it used in this book, as it will give an indication of what you're supposed to be learning from it) as well as indicate what research you've done on your own to try to figure out what that code snippet does (for example, if you don't understand a method or a keyword, have you looked up the documentation for that method/keyword?).

I've just noticed that was an answer by Servy, whom I've just noticed has posted a similar answer here.